# Simple Jenkins notifications in a closed network?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We are a small development team (4 developers) with the following environment:

- Windows 10 (64-bit)
- Jenkins version 2.150.2
- PCs connected through a **CLOSED NETWORK** (no Internet connections)
- no email

We would like to use Jenkins notifications, so developers would be automatically notified for example when a build gets broken.

Jenkins *Plugin Manager* lists many (several tens) plugins under the section *Build Notifiers*, but we are not sure which one would be appropriate.

Something like *Slack* is not an option, because Slack servers are cloud-based and we have a closed network.

Something like *Mattermost* (a self-hosted alternative to Slack) would be overkill: requires Windows Server, MySQL, and what not (see https://docs.mattermost.com/install/prod-windows-2012.html).

Basically, we just need a small window to pop up on developers' screens when something goes wrong in Jenkins. What would be a **simple** way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add [HipChat plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/hipchat-plugin) assuming you can setup an internal HipChat server

> HipChat Server Host: The hostname (and optionally the port number) for the HipChat server in use. Note that the server will always be accessed via HTTPS

And [send notification](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/jenkins-2-up/9781491979587/ch04.html) to users

> The HipChat Notification plugin provides the previously mentioned hipchatSend step that you can use in your pipeline. The only required (default) parameter is a message.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Do you know where one can find the HipChat server? According to Wikipedia, HipChat was acquired in 2012, and I can't find where to download the HipChat server.

Comment: @user1387866 see https://confluence.atlassian.com/hc/deploying-hipchat-server-609944387.html

Comment: The page says: *We support deploying the Hipchat Server OVA image on VMware and VirtualBox.* So, this server (file size = 2.7 GB!) is usable only with a virtual machine?!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AnyStatus](https://www.anystat.us/2019/09/01/jenkins-build-monitor.html) to monitor Jenkins jobs and views.

AnyStatus is a desktop notifications app for Windows that helps developers keep track of services such as Jenkins, Azure DevOps, TeamCity, AppVeyor and more. AnyStatus will notify you when your Jenkins jobs start, complete or fail. It shows the progress of jobs while they are running and enables you to start or stop jobs remotely.

AnyStatus can also monitor other resources such as databases, network, web servers, computer resources and more. You can also develop your own plugins.

AnyStatus is a standalone application that can run in a closed network.
No server or internet connection is required.

[image: AnyStatus]

Disclaimer: I am the author of AnyStatus.